# How can I loop through adding each list item and put them together?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write items from 3 different lists in a row (starting at 0), then going to a new line and writing the next set of items in the lists. e.g 0, 1, 2, etc.

How do I wrap this up in some sort of loop that would do this? Is it something where I make a count, then replace each `0` in my code with the `count` variable? I'm new to Python and coding in general and I'm struggling.

```py
names = []
number_grades = []
letter_grades = []


def write_to_output():
    file = open_file(output_grades, "w")
    # I'm stuck here
    file.write(str(names[0]) + ", " + str(number_grades[0]) + str(letter_grades[0]))
```

How do I loop through this and count up each loop, going through each item in the lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to iterate over multiple lists simultaneously:

```py
names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
number_grades = [4, 3, 2]
letter_grades = ['A', 'B', 'C']

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for name, num, let in zip(names, number_grades, letter_grades):
        f.write(f"{name}, {num} {let}\n")
```

Output (`output.txt`):

```
Alice, 4 A
Bob, 3 B
Charlie, 2 C
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative if you're not used to `zip` - but you can always check zip documentation.

```
names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
number_grades = [4, 3, 2]
letter_grades = ['A', 'B', 'C']

nbr_students = len(names)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(nbr_students):
        f.write(f"{names[i]}, {number_grades[i]}, {letter_grades[i]}")
```